# How does the Turbo Tax website work without full page postbacks?

Tags: jquery, single-page-application

I was looking through the Turbo Tax site (www.turbotax.com) and it appears, once you sign in, only the center panel changes, the other parts remain static and the entire page never does a full page postback. How does this work ? I realize it could be simply jquery ajax, but is there something deeper going on internally ?

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be just using Ajax or update panels.  We just created a whole CMS here with bunches of pages, modals, forms, etc, and we only have a couple places in the whole site that'll cause a full postback.  We used jQuery Ajax and json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a web-based single-page application (SPA). The first time a page is visited, the browser downloads all the HTML, CSS, Javascript, images and whatever other resources are needed to render the initial display. From that point on, however, only data necessary to adjust the inner components to reflect changes in the application's state has to travel over the network connection.  This makes the web application appear to be more responsive and interactive to the user, more like an application that was installed directly on the user's computer would behave.

AJAX is one frequently used method by which the necessary data exchange is performed, but additional methods include WebSockets or special browser plugins such as Adobe's Flash plugin.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application for more info on SPAs, including some pointers to tools and development libraries such as AngularJS that facilitate the process of developing SPAs.